# Can someone explain me Ciphersweet blind index planning?

Tags: php, encryption, searchable

I've read the docummentation about it but i can seem to understand. In the example they gave on this link : [Link to the page](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/blind-index-planning)

they said : Input domain is the set of all possible distinct inputs.

For example: Calendar years consisting of 4-digit integers (2019) have an input domain of 10,000 possible values. The log (base 2) of 10,000 is 13.2877; you would want to always round up (so 14).

Output size is the number of bits (not bytes) of a blind index.

Does it mean that we have to calculate manualy the input domain of evrey blind index we are about to add. If it is the case how can i calculate the blind index size of a string of 30 characters ?

here's somme additional code

```
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Planner\FieldIndexPlanner;
$planner = new FieldIndexPlanner();
$planner->setEstimatedPopulation(50000);
$recommended = $planner->recommend(14);
var_dump($recommended);
$field->addBlindIndex(
    new BlindIndex('birth_year_idx', [], 8, true)
);
// 8 is the output size (in bits) we decided previously
// 14 because log_2(10000) is larger than 13 but smaller than 14
$planner->addExistingIndex('birth_year_idx', 8, 14);
```

I don't really understand it can you please help me ?

Comment: This is about indexing, so I **guess** the application needs to know if every 30 character combination is possible.

Comment: How would it do that ?